# $\int _{B_\epsilon (0)}\frac{1}{|y|^{n-2}}dy=nw_n\int^\epsilon_0\frac{r^{n-1}}{r^{n-2}}dr$

Tags: calculus

$\int _{B_\epsilon (0)}\frac{1}{|y|^{n-2}}dy=nw_n\int^\epsilon_0\frac{r^{n-1}}{r^{n-2}}dr$
where $w_n$ is a volume of unit sphere of $n$ dimension, and $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

This is an elementary change of variable calculus, but could anybody help me show how this equality holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be careful with the terms as they both tend to infinity! But the proof you were looking is given by an application of "Cavalieri’s principle":

$\int \limits_{B_{\varepsilon}}\frac{1}{|y|^{n-2}}dy=\int \limits_0^{\varepsilon} \int \limits_{\partial B_{r}}\frac{1}{|\xi|^{n-2}}d\xi dr =\int \limits_0^{\varepsilon}\frac{1}{r^{n-2}}\cdot vol(\partial B_r)dr=n\cdot \omega_n\int \limits_0^{\varepsilon} \frac{r^{n-1}}{r^{n-2}}dr$

where $vol(\partial B_r)=n\cdot \omega_n r^{n-1}.$