# Looking for the theory to solve an integral.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

What is the theory that I have to study in order to solve this integral for $n\ge 4$?

$$\int_{B_r(0)}\frac{1}{|y|^{n-2}}\;dy$$ where $B_r(0)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n\;|\;\;\rVert y \lVert_{\mathbb{R}^n}\le r\}$

When I consider the polar coordinates I have to consider the limit since the function is not defined in $0$?

Comment: is the ball in the $x,y$ plane? it is not clear how the geometry you describe relates to the variables in the integral

Comment: Not sure how useful it is, but you can use the coarea formula to show that $\int_{B_r(0)}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\lVert y\rVert^{n-2}}=\int_0^r\int_{\partial B_R(0)}\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(y)}{\lVert y\rVert^{n-2}}~\mathrm{d}R$

Comment: @Larago But, the integrand function though is not $C^0$ in the ball.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball - part "Direct integration in spherical coordinates"

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4037171/42969.

Comment: when i switch to polar coordinates i have to consider the limit since the function is not defined in 0?

Comment: @NatMath you could always remove an $\varepsilon$-ball at the origin in the integration domain and then let $\varepsilon\to0$ at the end if you don't want to have to worry about it being undefined at the origin